# Does the iPhone 4 geo-tag photos without a data connection?

Tags: iphone, photos, geolocation

In a few weeks, I will have the iPhone 4. I won't take data with SMS-call hours. But I love taking pictures wherever I go, and the geo-tagging feature is a great thing.

Does the iPhone 4 geo-tag pictures usefully even without data?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes; The Geo tags are written into the images via the native Location Services within the phone, primarily via the GPS chip the phone contains.

Since the information written is merely latitude/longitude, you do not need to have a data connection in order for that information to be determined and added.

The need for a data connection in tandem with photos is the ability to place them on a map, when using iPhoto for example.

Comment: Even if the GPS is low quality or you are on a device without GPS, iOS keeps a cache of potential base station WiFi (and in the case of cell phones - cellular towers) so that all three radio signals (GPS, cell, WiFi) could be used to assist in geolocating without a working data connection.

Comment: Yep, now I'm using an iTouch and I knew for the wifi database. But the cellular tower I didn't know. Thanks :-)