# Does GPS tagging for camera images work without wifi connection with iphone 5?

Tags: iphone, gps, image-editing

I want to make pictures with the iphone 5 and want the position information (GPS) in it.
Is it possible to tag pictures without any internet connection?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does the iPhone 4 geo-tag photos without a data connection?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/76210/does-the-iphone-4-geo-tag-photos-without-a-data-connection)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It does extremely well with geo-tagging photos without an internet connection. The phone simply saves the lat/longitude in the photo file.

What one needs a data connection for is *viewing* the images on a map - one must download the map to display the pins.